# how to style 2 nd element in div

Tags: html, css

I want to apply css style to the 2nd child element of div.

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="my">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.my:nth-child(1) {
    color:red;
}
```

This applying style to every element. Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AkCLY/

Comment: you only have one instance of ".my" so there is no second child haha, try ".my div:nth-child(2)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its like this:

```
.my div:nth-child(1) {
    color:red;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/AkCLY/1/)

As you want the second one you want to change the `1` to `2`

so `.my div:nth-child(2)`

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/AkCLY/12/)

Comment: I believe he is looking for the second child to be styled, you are styling the first.

Comment: @ChrisHardie I didn't think I needed to point that out as its pretty obvious but I have edited my answer to point it out.

Answer (score 2):

You were almost on it. Just add a space and it should work:

```
.my > :nth-child(1) {
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: (maybe you should add a first descendent selector thoug : .my > :nth-child(1))

Answer (score 0):

This will adjust the color of the second child, as you requested:

```
.my div:nth-child(2) {
    color:red;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AkCLY/8/

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one:

```
.my div:nth-child(2) {
    color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
.my div:nth-child(2) 
{
    color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
.my div:nth-child(2) {
    color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this code ..

```
.my div:nth-child(2) 
{
    color:red;
}
```